# How to visualize the findAssocs() result from tm

Tags: r, data-visualization, text-mining, tm

I've extracted some tweets and put them into a term document matrix. Next I started looking for word associations - words which most frequently occur together.

`tweets_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(tweets_corpus)`

`findAssocs(tweets_tdm, 'stackoverflow', 0.20)`

I get results which look like:

`programming               0.33
java                       0.27
moderator                  0.27`

How can I visualize these results apart from doing a bar chart / pie chart ? I would like to do a visualization which has the search word "stackoverflow" as the axis / hub and the associated words as the node or spokes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a perspective from using the `igraph` package and one version of the possible output.  There are more choices for formatting, of course.

```
terms <- c("programming", "java", "moderator", "extraword")
probs <- c(0.33, 0.27, 0.27, .55)
df <- data.frame(terms = terms, probs = probs)
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE)
plot(g)
```

[image]